# How to enforce unique file names when uploading to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 bucket and have granted access customer to upload file in it. Is there a way to ensure that object names are unique in the S3 bucket without enforcing this requirement on the customer who uploads the file?

I see S3 have versioning capabilities but the object with same name may not be versions of same object but rather totally different object whose names matched unintentionally

Comment: Sadly, there's no IAM policy-based solution that will allow upload but prevent overwrite. They're the same thing as far as policies are concerned. Object versioning, object lock, or a custom application that vends unique URLs (potentially pre-signed) are typical solutions (each with its own drawback).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Amazon S3 Object Lock feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock-overview.html). It can help you prevent objects from being deleted or overwritten for a fixed amount of time or indefinitely.

*Note: There are two modes: **Governance Mode** and **Compliance Mode**.*

In your case you probably should use **Governance Mode**.

The difference is that in **Governance Mode**, users can't overwrite or delete an object version or alter its lock settings *unless they have special permissions*. With Governance Mode, you protect objects against being deleted by most users, but you can still *grant some users permission to alter the retention settings or delete the object* if necessary.

In **Compliance Mode**, a protected object version *can't be overwritten or deleted by any user, including the root user in your AWS account*. When an object is locked in Compliance Mode, its retention mode can't be changed, and its retention period can't be shortened.